# C# - SQL not finding duplicate value in the primary key

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

this is a little hard to explain so please bear with me.
I working with a sql table via console c#.
I'm at the point where the end user needs to be able to modify the primary keys value eg classroom names
When the user tries to edit a primary key value that already exists, the first time round `sql / c#` `catches` it and gives an `Exception` and the program continues as normal looping it back to the part where the user input the duplicate primary key value.
 However when you try and add data once again and happen to add a value that already exists as a primary key value, it doesn't `catch` it the second time round.

**Here is a timeline**.

1. Enter the new group menu
2. Update details on a groups name, however that groups name already
   exists so it tells the end user to try again and loops them back to
   the part asking to add a new group
3. End user adds the correct details and continues working with the
   program
4. Later the end user tries to update the details of a group and add a name that already exists, however this time it doesn't raise an `Exception` but continues working when it shouldn't.

Here is the code behind from the loop that was mentioned above.

 **UPDATE: adding all of the module to answer some of the comments below.**

```
static void editTable()
    {
        int j = 0;
    top:
        SQLCONN.Open();
        var TIME = DateTime.Now;
        SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo."+selectedDayTableToEdit+"Table", SQLCONN);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd0.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int n = 1;
            int p = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("  [" + reader.GetValue(n).ToString() + " TIMES]     [TEACHER / CLASSROOM]      {0} " + TIME.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), selectedDayTitle);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");

            for (int i = 2; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p +" - " + reader.GetName(i) + "      " + reader.GetValue(i));
                p++;
            }
        }

        SQLCONN.Close();
        repeat:
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Which group would you like to edit?");
        string Group = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}'s new group name if any", Group);
        string newGroup = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroup))
        {
            check = true;
            newGroup = string.Format("{0}", Group);
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
        }
        SQLCONN.Open();
        //update Group Name (SAT)
        try
        {
               if(check == false)
            {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + selectedDayTableToEdit + "Table SET CLASSNAME=@CLASSNAME where CLASSNAME=@" + Group, SQLCONN))//2nd @ what its looking for.
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CLASSNAME", newGroup);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + Group, Group);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("That group already exists");
            Console.ReadKey();
            SQLCONN.Close();
            goto repeat;
        }
        SQLCONN.Close();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Which time would you like to edit for group {0}?", newGroup);
        string RESULT = Console.ReadLine();
        string ClassTime = "";
        switch (RESULT)
        {
            case "1":
                ClassTime = "09:00-09:40";
                break;
            case "2":
                ClassTime = "10:10-10:50";
                break;
            case "3":
                ClassTime = "11:00-11:40";
                break;
            case "4":
                ClassTime = "11:50-12:30";
                break;
            case "5":
                ClassTime = "12:40-13:20";
                break;
            case "6":
                ClassTime = "13:30-14:10";
                break;
            case "7":
                ClassTime = "14:20-15:00";
                break;
            case "8":
                ClassTime = "15:10-15:50";
                break;
            case "9":
                ClassTime = "16:00-16:40";
                break;
            case "10":
                ClassTime = "16:50-17:30";
                break;
            case "11":
                ClassTime = "17:40-18:20";
                break;
            case "12":
                ClassTime = "18:30-19:10";
                break;
            case "13":
                ClassTime = "19:20-20:00";
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("A time was not selected...");
                Console.WriteLine("Returning to main menu");
                Console.ReadKey();
                menu();
                break;
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("Enter the current teacher and classroom for {0}", newGroup); // DONT NEED THIS ANYMORE??
        //string teacherandclassroom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Enter the new teacher and classroom number for group {0} at {1} ", newGroup, ClassTime));
        string newTeacherClassRoom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        SQLCONN.Open();
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE "+selectedDayTableToEdit+"Table SET [" + ClassTime + "] = @newValue WHERE [CLASSNAME] =@" + newGroup, SQLCONN)) //or WHERE newGroup?
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newTeacherClassRoom); //@ can be whatever as long as its the same as the queries
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + newGroup, newGroup);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
            }
            SQLCONN.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            SQLCONN.Close();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR UPDATING RECORDS....");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            if (j == 1)
            {
                menu();

            }
            else
            {
                j++;
                goto top;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I have since added an `ID` primary key using an integer and removed the `GC`
Thanks everyone for commenting and giving me suggestions on what I should be doing, much appreciated indeed!
The problem was to do with the `check` boolean, thanks everyone that pointed that out.

Comment: You should try to avoid using a primary key value that you care enough about to want to change it in future database designs. It generates all kinds of headaches when doing updates.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind @LasseV.Karlsen :) For this database, the user wont be changing a primary keys values on a day to day bases, this is just for on the off chance they do.

Comment: @Werdna . . . You should have an identity column as the primary key, with the name as an attribute.  You can create a unique constraint on the name to ensure no duplication.

Comment: The code above should not give the mentioned problem. Something different is at play here. (However using as PrimaryKey a field that you plan to be able to modify is really a bad practice to do and rarely justifiable)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, I will change the primary key to integers instead of group names, and see how we go, @Steve yeah that's what i thought, no too worries but, I'll fix up the table and see what happens next. Thanks again everyone! :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen While true, he'll still have this problem if that column is marked as unique instead of as primary key.

Comment: What is the value of `check` when you give it a second go? I see that you are jumping to `repeat` only when you get an exception. What happens if you don't get one? What is the initial value of `check`?

Comment: hey @Andrei15193 You were right, I removed the `check` bool and it has worked as expected, thanks for that :)

Comment: You need to show more of your code. At the bare minimum, the entire function.

Comment: hey @JonathanAllen, first of all. thank you for your answer, well not answer but you know what I mean, second, I didn't want to post too much code as I have seen other users get slammed for posted too much code.

Comment: @Werdna, my bet is that `check` got set to `true` through some execution and remained that way even when you typed a new group name that is not an empty string.

Comment: So you used exact code from my answer but did not give up the check?

Comment: Users never have to edit primary keys. Users don't know that primary keys exist. That is one reason why a primary key should be meaningless, like an `int` or a `Guid`. If it has no meaning then there's no reason to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check = true; //weird because its working if false???
```

you know what is weird is you don't set it false

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroup))
{
    newGroup = string.Format("{0}", Group);  // what is the purpose of this?
    check = true; //weird because its working if false???
}
else 
    check = false;
```

agree with other answer on

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupName", Group);
```

and on do NOT do this

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

and you fail to check group for null or empty

why are even opening the connection if

```
if (check == false)
```

a little cleaner

```
    repeat:
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Which group would you like to edit?  Blank to exit.");
    string Group = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Group))
        exit;  // this may be return - I forget
    Console.WriteLine("Enter {0}'s new group name if any", Group);
    string newGroup = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newGroup))
        goto repeat;
    SQLCONN.Open();
    //update Group Name (SAT)
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd =
        new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + selectedDayTableToEdit + "Table SET SAAT=@NewGroup where SAAT=@SAAT", SQLCONN))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewGroup", newGroup);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saat", Group);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("That group already exists");
    }
    finally 
    {
        SQLCONN.Close();
    }
    goto repeat;
```

Comment: Cheers Paparazzi for your help, I ended up changing the table so the primary key wasn't to be changed and also ended up keeping the check part, I used the "string.IsNullOrEmptry (newGroup))" that you suggested, very nice indeed :)

Comment: And this answer still does not have a check.

Comment: Hey @Paparazzi, I wasn't too use if i was to make it as correct since I used everyone's input??

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some notes too big for comments:

```
        SQLCONN.Open();
```

This line concerns me. You should be creating a new connection each time with a `using` block to make sure it is properly destroyed. Sharing a connection object is really hard to do correctly, even when not multi-threading.

Note: Technically speaking, closing a connection doesn't actually close it. It just returns it to a connection pool for reuse later. But that's not something you have to think about.

---

```
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Don't mess around with the garbage collector. That's a very advanced technique that is only applicable to some forms of testing and incredibly high performance applications. And even then, learning how to do it correctly is hard.

---

```
   new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + selectedDayTableToEdit + "Table SET SAAT=@SAAT where SAAT=@" + Group, SQLCONN))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saat", newGroup);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + Group, Group);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
            }
```

That's really, really bad. You are creating a SQL statement using arbitraty text. If someone says the same of the group is "tom; Delete FROM MyTable" then you will delete everything in the table.

Beyond that, changing the variable name every time will cause it to create a new execution plan every time.

```
   new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + selectedDayTableToEdit + "Table SET SAAT=@SAAT where SAAT=@GroupName", SQLCONN))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Saat", newGroup);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupName", Group);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Database Updated...");
            }
```

I don't like `selectedDayTableToEdit + "Table` either, but that's unavoidable when the table name can change. Still, it would be far better to create one big table so you can write:

```
 new SqlCommand("UPDATE DatTable SET SAAT=@SAAT where SAAT=@GroupName AND DayToEdit=@Day", SQLCONN))
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Allen for your insight as to what I would be doing, I haven't had too much to do with tables from C# console before, so its still fairly new, thank you answer for your reply, I will be sure to go over it again and again :)